# Remove (jQuery) at the end of plugin code

Tags: jquery

I have the following plugin which is working:

```
(function ($) {

  $.fn.slider = function (options) {

    var defaults = {
      pause: 8000
    };

    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    $(this).each(function () {

       // Ommited code for simplicity       

    });

    return this;

  };

})(jQuery);
```

If I change the first and last line to:

```
$(function () {
  // Inner code
});
```

Shouldn't this work? Do I need the (JQuery) at the end?

I think there is a format which does not require (JQuery) at the end.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the creation of a plugin with the use of jQuery itself.  This syntax:

```
$(function () {
    //...
});
```

tells jQuery to invoke the function when the DOM is ready.  Whereas this syntax:

```
(function ($) {
    //...
})(jQuery);
```

invokes the function immediately and passes it the jQuery object, to use as the `$` argument.  You *can* omit it:

```
(function () {
    //...
})();
```

*However*, this is no longer self-contained and runs the risk of not working if `$` is ever anything other than the jQuery object.  Other plugins and libraries might use `$` themselves, but are very unlikely to use the variable `jQuery` themselves.

When creating your plugin, you want it to be invoked immediately and not wait until the DOM is ready.  That way other code which uses the plugin will be able to use it and avoid race conditions with loading code.

Answer (score 1):

The first example you have runs jQuery in a [IIFE](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/#use-an-immediately-invoked-function-expression) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). Nothing wrong with that and it prevents collisions or conflicts with other libraries that also use `$`. The second example is just a shorthand method of jQuery's [document.ready function](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) which runs your code when the DOM is safe to manipulate.